# Error While compiling U-Boot

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling

```
/bin/bash: arm-linux-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-linux-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
Generating include/autoconf.mk
/bin/bash: line 2: arm-linux-gcc: command not found
Generating include/autoconf.mk.dep
/bin/bash: line 2: arm-linux-gcc: command not found
Configuring for zynq_zybo board...
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~/zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` and create a symbolic link

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ld /usr/bin/arm-linux-ld
```

Can you see the system? **;)** Create a symbolic links with the original name, simply remove `gnueabi-`.

Comment: but I still see a small error at /bin/bash: arm-linux-ld: command not found

Comment: Updated my answer =)